# Executing adb from php

Tags: php, android, adb

I am trying to run adb from PHP using:

```
exec( 'adb devices', $output, $return_val );
```

but I get 126 error.

I think the problem is that php is running as 'www-data' user and does not have permissions to execute adb.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this site out:
http://bzed.de/posts/2009/05/howto_set_android_developer_device_permissions_with_udev/

And add www-data to androiddev. 
You need to add your specific model to the udev-lines. You can find the vendor- and product-id by connecting your phone to your computer and executing lsusb in a terminal.

You get something like:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:a001 Dell Computer Corp. Hub
```

where 413c is the Vendor ID and  a001 is the ID of the product. Of course, your cell phone should be the line instead of "Dell Computer"...

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on Windows, the easier solution that I know is:

1. Create a file.bat with the order adb devices and the variables $1 and $2.
2. Call the file.bat with php using exec command

That should work.

If you are working on Linux, use a /bin/bash. And use the same procedure.

Your friend google will help you if don't know how to do the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a solution for 126 error, it's a way to run adb from php on Linux Debian 8.

If you have installed **android-tools-adb**, surely have noted that a new group has be created: **adb**, the user `www-data` must belong to it:

```
usermod -a -G adb www-data
```

And if you have using a Android version greater than or equal to 4.4.2 you need to [accept RSA key fingerprint](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements43) on screen on your cell phone, that at the same time [makes a hidden directory](https://source.android.com/source/add-device) in your computer named `.android` on user home path, there, will be stored both *adbkey* and *adbkey.pub* files, running:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data
```

You get

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www
```

Therefore, /var/www is for www-data user,

So, I changed its group from root to www-data

```
chown root:www-data /var/www
```

Then, I set write permissions

```
chmod 775 /var/www/
```

Now, `.android` directory can be created. Despite the [message](https://support.mobiledit.com/portal/kb/articles/android-confirm-rsa-fingerprint) when you're going to accept RSA key fingerprint says: "*Always allow from this computer*", you must accept each user for computer if adb command is being used by different users on the same computer

And you can just try the [adb command as www-data user](https://serverfault.com/questions/388016/bash-scripting-su-to-www-data-for-single-command/566457#566457), executing: (as root)

```
sudo -u www-data adb devices -l
```

I hope this helps someone else